# Using a let variable in message.content.send in discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I'm basically making a counting bot where one command shows a let in a message, one increments it and sends a message, and, once I get passed this little issue, one that will let me set the let in case someone goes overboard. It's for a D&D campaign using discord and is basically just a meme bot I'm making for fun. The issue I'm having is that I can't figure out how to use the let variable in the message itself.  This is what I'm working with based on youtube and my previous experience in Python, of which there is little.

```
const { prefix, token } = require('./Config.json');
const client = new Discord.Client();
let insight = 4;

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log("Ready!")
})

client.on('message', message => {
    console.log(message.content);
    if(message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}insight`)) {
        return message.channel.send("Ghyger had distrusted someone ", insight, " times!")
    }
    if(message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}distrust`)) {
        insight++;
        return message.channel.send("Not again Ghyger! That's ", insight, " times now!")
    }
})

client.login(token);
```

When this is ran and I execute either command, it throws up this, followed by a bunch of paths

```
options.reply = reply;
                  ^

TypeError: Cannot create property 'reply' on number '5'
```

Comment: Where is the `let` variable ?

Comment: please show more code

Comment: Edited it to show the full code

Answer (score 0):

It's because `reply` is a function, not a variable, you should be calling it `options.reply(reply);`.

Answer (score -1):

Fix is `let option.reply = reply`

Comment: That's not valid JS and will return a `SyntaxError`.